# Display a tree structure inside a box in MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab, treeview, tree, jtree

I have a problem to see the tree structure created by the following code. I want the tree box fulfills the interior of the pane which handle is hPanLeft. However, if I use normalized units, I get NaN and Inf for the Position property of the tree structure. I do not understand what is wrong.

```
  function example
    import javax.swing.*
    import javax.swing.tree.*;
    f = figure;
    hPanRight = uipanel('Parent',f,'Units','normalized','Position',...
        [0.5 0 0.5 0.5]);
    hPanLeft = uipanel('Parent',f,'Units','normalized','Position',...
        [0 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
    [tree, container]= uitree('v0');
    set(container,'Parent',hPanLeft);
    set(tree, 'Units', 'normalized');
    set(tree,'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
    get(tree,'Position'),
    root = uitreenode('v0','root','MAIN',[],false);
    Nodo1 = uitreenode('v0','Nodo1','LEAF 1',[],true);
    Nodo2 = uitreenode('v0','Nodo2','LEAF 2',[],true);
    Nodo3 = uitreenode('v0','Nodo3','LEAF 3',[],true);
    root.add(Nodo1);
    root.add(Nodo2);
    root.add(Nodo3);
    treeModel = DefaultTreeModel(root);
    tree.setModel(treeModel);
    jtree = handle(tree.getTree,'CallbackProperties');
    tree.setSelectedNode(root);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the position property of the container not the tree object handle:

```
[tree,container] = uitree('v0');
set(container, 'Parent',hPanLeft);
set(container, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
```

[image: screenshot]

Just remember that UITREE is an undocumented function. You might want to read this [series of articles](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitree/) on this component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to resize the tree instead of the container. Is there some function o tree property to see the tree completely expanded (i.e. see the overall structure when it is first created without having to select each node and lead)?

Comment: @jpeji: you would have to call the EXPAND function. In your example, you could expand the root node as: `tree.expand(root);`